# Как организовать сортировку по расстоянию до объекта?

Tags: php, сортировка, mysql

Здравствуйте! У меня есть две таблицы. В одной (`config`) задается общая широта и долгота объекта. В другой (`place`) записаны достопримечательности, находящиеся возле объекта, у которых имеются свои параметры широты и долготы - `lat` и `lon`.

Так вот, нужно вывести достопримечательности в порядке возрастания расстояния до объекта `$latlon`. Пока что у меня идет сортировка по `pid` (уникальному `id`), расстояния, соответственно, вразброс.

Подскажите, как такое организовать?

Вот пример выборки из базы координат достопримечательностей и преобразования их в километраж до объекта:

```
// выбор общей широты и долготы, задается один раз
$result2 = $db->sql_query("SELECT * FROM config");
$row2 = $db->sql_fetchrow($result2);
$latlon = $row2['latlon']; // выводится, к примеру, так: 43.78,39.47

// выбираем достопримечательности из таблицы
$result = $db->sql_query("SELECT * FROM place ORDER BY pid ASC");
$first = $db->sql_numrows($result);

if ($first > 0) {

    while ($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result)) {
        $title = stripslashes(check_html($row['title'], "nohtml"));
        $lat1 = $row['lat'];
        $lon1 = $row['lon'];

        echo '<div class="placePages">
                  ' . $title . ' - ';

        if ($lat1) {
            echo 'расстояние до объекта: <span class="distance">' . distance($lat1, $lon1, $latlon) . '</span>'; // здесь рассчитывается дистанция в километрах до объекта, т.е. до $latlon
        }
        echo '</div>
    }
}

// функция расчета дистанции
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $latlon)
{
    $latlon2 = explode(",", $latlon);
    $lat2 = $latlon2[0];
    $lon2 = $latlon2[1];

    // Convert degrees to radians.
    $lat1 = deg2rad($lat1);
    $lon1 = deg2rad($lon1);
    $lat2 = deg2rad($lat2);
    $lon2 = deg2rad($lon2);

    // Calculate delta longitude and latitude.
    $delta_lat = ($lat2 - $lat1);
    $delta_lng = ($lon2 - $lon1);

    return round(6378137 / 1000 * acos(cos($lat1) * cos($lat2) * cos($lon1 - $lon2) + sin($lat1) * sin($lat2)), 1) . '&nbsp;км';
}
```

За `sql_query` прошу не судить, движок старый, скоро переделаю.

Comment: "Для этого вам сначала надо сохранить все данные в массив, отсортировать их по расстоянию до объекта, и сгенерировать HTML по уже отсортированным данным."

@VladD, Я не смогу это сделать... Буду пробовать js-ом.

Comment: @MyNameIs: Почему не сможете? В чём сложность?

Comment: не умею.))

Comment: ок, буду пробовать)

Comment: а сделайте комментарий ответом, пожалуйста

Comment: @MyNameIs: Добавил в ответ. Там немного больше кода.

Comment: @MyNameIs: **ВАЖНО** Сейчас ваша функция `distance` не вполне правильна: она возвращает не число, а строку, а сравнение по строке будет неправильное: `100 > 99`, но `"100 км" < "99 км"`. Поэтому сделайте так: пусть `distance` возвращает просто число, а в текстовый вид приводите его в самом конце, при выводе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас есть две возможные стратегии.

Либо вы знаете расстояние от достопримечательности до объекта на уровне базы данных, либо вычисляете их на лету.

Для первого варианта, в таблице `place` появится дополнительное поле, задающее расстояние достопримечательности до объекта. Вам нужно туда внести правильные значения один раз. В этом случае в запросе вы просто используете `order by` по этому полю.

Для второго варианта вам нужно отсортировать пришедшие данные запроса по расстоянию. Для этого вам сначала надо сохранить все данные в массив, [отсортировать](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php) их по расстоянию до объекта, и сгенерировать HTML по уже отсортированным данным.

Я бы посоветовал не полениться и пойти первым путём.

---

Попробуйте сделать так:

1) Заводите структуру, в которой будут храниться данные. Например, класс или массив.

2) В цикле делаете вот что:

```
$alldata = array();
while ($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result))
{
    // $alldata[] = <тут создаём структуру (например, подмассив) и пакуем в неё данные из $row>
    // например:
    $datum = array();
    $datum['title'] = stripslashes(check_html($row['title'], "nohtml"));
    $lat = $row['lat'];
    $lon = $row['lon'];
    $datum['lat'] = $lat;
    $datum['lon'] = $lon;
    $datum['distance'] = distance($lat, $lon, $latlon);
    // и остальные данные тоже пакуем
    $alldata[] = $datum;
}
```

3) Сортируем (usort)

4) Выводим:

```
foreach ($alldata as $datum)
{
    // достаёте данные из структуры
    $title = $datum['title'];
    $lat = $datum['lat'];
    $lon = $datum['lon'];
    echo '<div class="placePages"> ...
}
```

Comment: Дело в том, что мне хотелось бы автоматизировать модуль достопримечательностей до уровня "easy", т.е. пользователю не нужно самому вычислять расстояния, они задаются кликом по карте. Не хотелось бы заводить доп. поле в базе, т.к. для другого сайта с этим же модулем расстояния будут меняться, удаленность от объекта ведь другая. 

Второй вариант слишком громоздкий.

Comment: Видимо придется воспользоваться js плагином isotope, который сортирует по всякому.

Comment: @MyNameIs: Эээ... Пользователю вообще ничего не надо вычислять, вычислять должна ваша процедура при внесении достопримечательности в базу.

Comment: А если достопримечательности уже в базе? Пользователь в конфиге устанавливает только свою точку на карте и все.

Comment: @MyNameIs: Вы имеете в виду, что достопримечательности не привязаны к конкретному объекту, объект может меняться, а достопримечательности те же самые?

Comment: Да... Можно, наверное, создать функцию пересчета расстояний и незаметно привязать ее к какому-нибудь событию в админке. Но я думала, что можно как-то объединить запросы к базе при выборке всех  `place`, что-то типа `$result = $db->sql_query("SELECT * FROM place ORDER BY " . distance(lat, lon, $latlon) . " ASC");`, но этот вариант , конечно же, неправильный.

Comment: Не, так не пойдёт, по идее. Модифицировать базу на лету не стоит. Ещё один вариант — вычисляйте расстояние и включайте в выводимые данные, на стороне клиента можно отсортировать по этой колонке javascript'ом. (Но не забудьте, что у юзера js может быть выключен.) Так что мне кажется, вам нужен второй вариант.